# Override partial class field in ASP MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model

In my ASP MVC project, whenever I add a new table to my project two models are created. One under the Text Templating Transformation Toolkit (file w/`.tt` extension), and another outside this in the general `Models` folder (this one seems to want to default with a "1" at the end of the file).

[image]

Whenever a change is made to the database, it seems all the models under the `.tt` file are refreshed according to the fields currently existing in the database on that table. The files outside this is the general `Models` folder, however are left as they were. Because of this, we have put all of our model validation methods in these `.cs` files (with the "1" at the end of the file name).

However, in one instance I needed to remove a field from the model under the `.tt` file in order to perform a validation in the other `.cs` file. This is the validation I perform:

```
    private string agentId;

    //here, AgentId overrrides the field in the BankListAgentId.cs file, 
    //which MUST be commented out.
    [DisplayName("Agent ID")]
    public string AgentId
    {
        get { return agentId; }
        set { agentId = this.scrubAgentId(value); }
    }
```

Is there a way to specify in this `.cs` file that the `AgentId` field here (the file with the "1" at the end of the name) overrides the `AgentId field in the`.cs`file found under the`.tt` file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it can't be done. But there are few tricks that can you do.

1. Change name of your property to eg. InternalAgentId and also change in EDMX that field to be protected or even private. Then in your code reference to InternalAgentId:

   ```
   public string AgentId
   {
       get { return this.InternalAgentId; }
       set { this.InternalAgentId = this.ScrubAgentId(value); }
   }
   ```

   If you need that property in linq you can look at [Microsoft Linq Translation](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider)
2. Another way is to change your T4 to generate partial methods and invoking it inside generated properties. I think that one of Entity Framework template already do that.